# How to efficiently group a sorted flux into serialized groups in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

Let's say I have an input `Flux` containing many (billions of strings) like this:

- apple
- application
- bible
- book

There are billions of such strings, they won't fit into memory, that's why I want to use the reactive approach.

The stream is sorted. Now what I want is to create a flux of ordered groups of strings by the first 3 characters:

- app: apple, application
- bib: bible
- boo: book

This `Flux` ends up on an HTTP response which means that all "app" items must be outputted before "bib" items begin.

Without using `Flux` I could use the ordered property and collect the items into a prepared bucket (amount of strings per bucket will fit into memory) as they come - whenever the prefix changes, I will flush the bucket and start collecting new prefix. The big advantage of the stream being ordered is that I know that once I encounter new prefix, the old one will never come again.

But using `Flux` I don't know how to do this. The `.groupBy()` will return `Flux` of `Flux` but I don't think this will work when trying to serialize this to the HTTP response output stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty much a textbook use case for [`windowUntilChanged()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#windowUntilChanged-java.util.function.Function-).

In your case, the "key" you want to extract is the first 3 letters of the string, so you can do something like `flux.windowUntilChanged(str -> str.substring(0,3))`, which will give you a `Flux<Flux<String>>`, where the inner fluxes start and finish on change of the first 3 letters in your string. You may want to add some additional logic to deal with words less than 3 characters long of course, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :-)

(I know you've mentioned it in the question, but just for clarification and the sake of anyone else finding this answer - this will *only* work if the incoming elements on the stream are already sorted alphabetically.)